# npm ERR! path \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jdoe\DevProjects\litenotes\node_modules\.bin\autoprefixer

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, laravel, wsl-2

Presently, I am attempting to create a PHP laravel app and install some `nodejs` dependencies on `wsl-2` but am getting the following errors (cf. https://www.linkedin.com/learning/laravel-9-0-essential-training).  FYI, I have installed `nodejs` v18.16.0:

```
jdoe@Grieg:~/DevProjects/litenotes$ curl -s https://laravel.build/litenotes | bash
...
jdoe@Grieg:~/DevProjects/litenotes$  ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

In another terminal:

```
jdoe@Grieg:~/DevProjects/litenotes$ ./vendor/bin/sail composer require laravel/breeze --dev
...
jdoe@Grieg:~/DevProjects/litenotes$ ./vendor/bin/sail artisan breeze:install
...
jdoe@Grieg:~/DevProjects/litenotes$ npm install
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     '\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu-22.04\\home\\jdoe\\DevProjects\\litenotes\\node_modules\\.bin\\he',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, lstat '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jdoe\DevProjects\litenotes\node_modules\.bin\he'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4068,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EISDIR',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'lstat',
npm WARN cleanup       path: '\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu-22.04\\home\\jdoe\\DevProjects\\litenotes\\node_modules\\.bin\\he'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     '\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu-22.04\\home\\jdoe\\DevProjects\\litenotes\\node_modules\\.bin\\autoprefixer',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, lstat '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jdoe\DevProjects\litenotes\node_modules\.bin\autoprefixer'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4068,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EISDIR',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'lstat',
npm WARN cleanup       path: '\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu-22.04\\home\\jdoe\\DevProjects\\litenotes\\node_modules\\.bin\\autoprefixer'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     '\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu-22.04\\home\\jdoe\\DevProjects\\litenotes\\node_modules\\tailwindcss',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jdoe\DevProjects\litenotes\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: '\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu-22.04\\home\\jdoe\\DevProjects\\litenotes\\node_modules\\tailwindcss\\lib'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jdoe\DevProjects\litenotes\node_modules\.bin\autoprefixer
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR! EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, lstat '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jdoe\DevProjects\litenotes\node_modules\.bin\autoprefixer'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\psalm\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-14T05_45_26_819Z-debug-0.log
```

This is my npm version:

```
jdoe@Grieg:~/DevProjects/litenotes$ npm -v
9.6.6
```

Also, I have checked the following sites but don't have a solution yet:

[Cannot find module '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\mnt\c\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73992540/cannot-find-module-wsl-localhost-ubuntu-20-04-mnt-c-program-files-nodejs-node)

[NPM node_modules/.bin symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142438/npm-node-modules-bin-symlinks)

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Gave up on `wsl` and ended up going with `vagrant`:  https://www.vagrantup.com/

**Original answer:**

Ran these commands instead (see [npm install errors on vagrant/homestead/windows: EPROTO: protocol error, symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186123/npm-install-errors-on-vagrant-homestead-windows-eproto-protocol-error-symlink)):

```
$ sudo npm install --no-bin-links
$ npm run dev
```

Which should then open:

[image]

Then you should be able to connect to the `mysql` database using:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. The problem is on nodejs installation.

To install nodejs in WSL, do not use apt.
Use following guidance from microsoft:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl
```